# Changing WHERE clause using Correlated Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to run this query as if I ran it for each day in the past, take a look at CHANGE_ME, I need this to run over again for each day.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT(ids)) AS pears, 
           c.geo_date 
    FROM   fruit_factory a 
           INNER JOIN dim_user c 
                   ON c.id = a.user_id 
    WHERE  a.run_date > c.geo_date
           AND a.run_date < CHANGE_ME
    GROUP  BY 2
```

So I made a table with dates and used a sub-query:

```
SELECT dd.date, 

(SELECT Count(DISTINCT(ids)) AS pears 

    FROM   fruit_factory a 
           INNER JOIN dim_user c 
                   ON c.id = a.user_id 
    WHERE  a.run_date > c.geo_date
           AND a.run_date < dd.date
    GROUP  BY 2)
FROM dim_date
```

But I need the above to be broken down by another dimension

```
SELECT dd.date, 

(SELECT Count(DISTINCT(ids)) AS pears, 
           c.geo_date

    FROM   fruit_factory a 
           INNER JOIN dim_user c 
                   ON c.id = a.user_id 
    WHERE  a.run_date > c.geo_date
           AND a.run_date < dd.date
    GROUP  BY 2)
FROM dim_date
```

In which the response is; I can't have more than one column returned.

Please help.

Ridicule welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100 percent sure if I understood the question correctly. But I think Gordon Linoff is missing part of the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) AS pears,
    d.date, # This is what previously was CHANGE_ME
    c.geo_date
FROM fruit_factory a
JOIN dim_date d 
    ON a.run_date < d.date
LEFT JOIN dim_user u
    ON u.id = a.user_id 
WHERE a.run_date > u.geo_date
GROUP BY d.date, c.geo_date
```

Here is some explanation why the JOIN works.

Take these tables:

fruit_factory:

```
id      run_date          user_id
1       2015-08-30     3
2       2015-09-01     2
3       2015-09-02     1
```

dim_date:

```
date
2015-09-01
2015-09-02
```

previously:

```
SELECT ... WHERE date < CHANGE_ME.
```

For August 1st:

```
1       2015-08-30     3
```

For August 2nd:

```
1       2015-08-30     3
2       2015-09-01     2
```

Now you use the join, this is what the Join gives you:

```
id      run_date          user_id    d.date
1       2015-08-30     3              2015-09-01
1       2015-08-30     3              2015-09-02
2       2015-09-01     2              2015-09-02
```

As you see, the first row is there twice now, because the join condition was met for both dates.

If you now group by d.date and what you grouped before, it will be like running all the previous queries for one day at the same time: The group by d.date makes sure the other groupings are each run for one value for CHANGE_ME.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `join` instead . . .

```
SELECT d.date, Count(DISTINCT(ids)) AS pears, c.geo_date 
FROM fruit_factory a INNER JOIN
     dim_user c 
     ON c.id = a.user_id AND
        a.run_date > c.geo_date JOIN
     dim_date d
     WHERE a.run_date < d.date
GROUP BY c.geo_date ;
```

However, you can probably use analytic functions for this.  It is unclear exactly what you want, because the question doesn't have sample data and desired results.